# Cannot control the orange part size in Gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-layout, imageview

I'm using a ImageAdapter which extends the BaseAdapter.
After running the app, i found that the imageview in gridview cannot fill correctly.. refer to the picture below.. I tried to set `android:listselector ="@null"` in gridview, but is doesnt work... I just want the orange part disappears or fit the picture...it's too long now...

And here is the layoutinflator in ImageAdapter:

```
LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
myView = li.inflate(R.layout.six_item_layout, null);
```

This is the Gridview layout:

```
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/gridview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >
</GridView>
```

This is the framelayout

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Oh///I cannot  upload any pictures here... please refer:

http://hi.baidu.com/dishe_fiona/album/item/8a12c4143a292df5bd8f7059bc315c6035a87331.html

Comment: Oh///I cannot  upload any pictures here...

Comment: maybe you should try to change `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for GridView?

Comment: i think, problem is in `android:stretchMode="columnWidth"`, not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for everybody's suggestion, finally, i find the "hack" is that the imageview's height is set incorrectly which leads to the long orange in gridview...
here is the imageview code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="135dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want your grid of same size having images the same way that are shown in the picture, you can change your list selector to **transparent**. Otherwise, your gridview images are not alligned in a normal way. I don't know whether is it your requirement or not. But you can always change your listSelector.

Comment: for the transparent is another issue, though i set the attribute as        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent", the framelayout still cannot fill the grid view... but i found the root reason, please refer to my answer:)